# How to dynamically add nodes to cytoscape graph with concentric layout

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there a way to add nodes and edges to Cytoscape graph with concentric layout? Cy.add() function adds the nodes and edges to the graph without the init styling. Only way I can this, is by building the graph everytime I add a new node or edge

Answer (score 0):

When you add a node, it is positioned where you specify -- in the `position` field in its [JSON](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json).

If you don't want to manually specify a position, then run a [layout](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts).  In your specific case, you should probably be running the concentric layout again with the same options.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am calling the cy.elements().makeLayout(options) if I have a new node that need to be inserted into the layout. For edges, It can add it dynamically without generating the layout again. Is there a way I can pause the layout, so that It won't add the edges into the graph until I call a button that would push the edges into the layout. For ex - cy.add(edges) generates without calling new layout function.  I tried to stop layout by layout.stop(), but it still generates edges if I do cy.add(edges).