# Add nodes and edges to graph on fly?

Tags: cytoscape.js

How can I add nodes and edges to concentric layout dynamically? I am using cy.add() to add the nodes and edges every time I have new data. However it is not able to position the nodes in their respective level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically add ndoes to cytoscape graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964733/how-to-dynamically-add-ndoes-to-cytoscape-graph)

Answer (score 0):

When you add a node, it is positioned where you specify -- in the `position` field in its [JSON](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json).

If you don't want to manually specify a position, then run a [layout](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts).  In your specific case, you should probably be running the concentric layout again with the same options.

**Question is duplicate of [How to dynamically add ndoes to cytoscape graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964733/how-to-dynamically-add-ndoes-to-cytoscape-graph)**